# How Do I Get Search To Work In Another File?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

My issue is I can't get search to work when I use it on a header and want it to work on my orders file. I can not seem to get the input so it gives me a 404 error.

**My search on header from search_header.blade.php**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav w-100">
    <li class="nav-item w-100">
      <form class="nav-link mt-2 mt-md-0 d-none d-lg-flex search" action="{{url('search')}}" method="GET">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="search" style="color: white" class="form-control" placeholder="Search products">
        <input type="submit" style="margin-left: 50px" value="Search" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**Controller function associated with it**

```
public function searchdata(Request $request) {
        $searchText = $request->search;
        dd($searchText);
        $order = Order::where('name', 'LIKE', ""%$searchText%"")->orwhere('phone', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%")
        ->orwhere('product_title', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%")->get();
        return view('admin.view_order', compact('order'));
    }
```

In my view_order blade file I include the search.header file up top but it does not register the search term. What am I missing?

Comment: Remove `dd()` and extra double quotes `""%$searchText%""`.

Comment: when do you get 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote it like this and it works now thanks for the help.

```
public function searchdata(Request $request) {
        $searchText = $request->search;
        $order = Order::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%")->orwhere('phone', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%")
        ->orwhere('product_title', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%")->get();
        return view('admin.view_order', compact('order'));
    }
```